# Google Cloud, compute.instances.aggregatedList with filter fails

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer

The google cloud API for compute.instances.aggregatedList includes filter argument.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/instances/aggregatedList

I use (status eq "RUNNING") as a filter to view all my running instances.

I would like to have a more elaborate criteria, such as one that uses labels and or other terms, however even the Google documentation terms (that use OR operator) returns an error, For example - even Google documentation example:
 (cpuPlatform = "Intel Skylake") OR (cpuPlatform = "Intel Broadwell")
fails with error 400:

> "message": "Invalid value for field 'filter': ' (cpuPlatform = \"Intel
>   Skylake\") OR (cpuPlatform = \"Intel Broadwell\")'. Invalid list
>   filter expression."

it looks as if the '=' signs are not accepted, and AND/OR operators are not accepted.
What is the correct format for this API.

Comment: I have no idea but I'm having the same problem, I'm just trying to filter on a simple name and getting a 400.

Comment: Would you tell how to reproduce ? thanks

Comment: Go to the gcloud api explorer for list here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list and enter valid project, zone, and filter. It returns a successful 200. Go to api explorer for aggregated list here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList and enter valid project and same filter leaving off the zone. I would expect the aggregated list to apply the filter to all zones in the project. Instead get a 400 with the filter error noted in the question. Let me know if screenshots would help - I'll have to wait till I'm home.

Comment: Hi there, I've just opened a public issue for this matter https://issuetracker.google.com/80238913

Comment: Thanks, let's see how it goes...

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when I used "=" instead of "eq" in google-api-python-client. I required to use labels to filter the aggregated instances list. At first I used

```
filter="labels.projectid=test-project"
```

which returned 400 error in aggregated list but was successful if it was queried for instances of specific zone.

I achieved the list successfully when I used filter as

```
filter="labels.projectid eq \"test-project\""
```

or

```
filter = "labels.projectid eq test-project"
```

I even tested it using REST-Client provided by google and it worked.
Reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/80238913

Answer (score 2):

Even 3 years later Google haven't fixed the bug: `OR` and `AND` operators are not supported even it is advertised:

- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList

Google API is famous for inconsistency and false promises. Just relax and do 2 queries to emulate `OR`.

For `AND` operator just omit AND and quote comparison expressions into parentheses:

```
(name eq 'stage-.*') (labels.env ne "SKIP")
```

Note I use `eq` / `ne` with regex instead of operators `=`, `!=`, `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Compute instances list api filter param should work with

`(labels.<label_name_1>=<label_value_1>) OR (labels.<label_name_2>=<label_value_2>)`

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this string works as a filter within Python:

```
test_filter = '((labels.test="test-value") AND (labels.test-second="test-second-value")) OR ((labels.test="test-other-value"))'
```

Answer (score 0):

This filter worked for me:

```
name eq my-service-v.*
```

Will return groups like `my-service-v112` etc' (even though the name field is nested inside).

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a similar error message calling a GCP API. I finally got it to work by making the filter look like this:

```
fmt.Sprintf("selfLink = \"%s\"", networkLink)
```